# Jupyter HTML Video playback speed

Tags: python, html, video, jupyter, playback

I know I can display a video in a Jupyter notebook like this:

```
from IPython.display import HTML

HTML("""
    <video alt="test" controls>
        <source src="test.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
""")
```

But does there exist a way to control the playback speed? For example playing a video at half speed.

Comment: using Google `html video speed` I found [HTML | DOM Video playbackRate Property](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/html-dom-video-playbackrate-property/) but it may need JavaScript code to set it.

Comment: Now that we have ipywidgets supporting Video(s), how could we change speed there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `Jupyter Notebook` when you right click on video then you should see context menu and there you can change speed.

`Jupyter Lab` doesn't have speed in this menu.

If you want to set speed at start then you have to use `playbackRate` in `JavaScript`

```
from IPython.display import HTML

HTML("""
<video alt="test" controls id="theVideo">
  <source src="https://archive.org/download/Popeye_forPresident/Popeye_forPresident_512kb.mp4">
</video>

<script>
video = document.getElementById("theVideo")
video.playbackRate = 4.0;
</script>
""")
```

The same way you can also create buttons to control speed.

```
from IPython.display import HTML

HTML("""
<button id="speed_4.0">Speed 4.0</button>
<button id="speed_0.5">Speed 0.5</button>

<hr>

<video alt="test" controls id="theVideo">
  <source src="https://archive.org/download/Popeye_forPresident/Popeye_forPresident_512kb.mp4">
</video>
    
<script>
video = document.getElementById("theVideo");
//video.playbackRate = 4.0;

document.getElementById("speed_4.0").addEventListener("click", function(){ 
    video.playbackRate = 4.0;
});

document.getElementById("speed_0.5").addEventListener("click", function(){ 
    video.playbackRate = 0.5;
});
</script>
""")
```

---

If you put the same code in next cell then buttons may not works and you may have to use new IDs for buttons and video. IDs should be unique.

Maybe it would need some other code to automatically generate unique IDs in every cell.

---

In code I put URL to real video [Popeye for President](https://archive.org/download/Popeye_forPresident/Popeye_forPresident_512kb.mp4) so everyone can test it.

Comment: I should have mentioned I'm using JupyterLab. It looks like there's no context menu with right-click, and the javascript buttons don't seem to have any effect. But The second option of setting speed at start works beautifully, thank you!

Comment: first I tested only with `jupyter notebook`. But now I tested also with `jupyter lab` and it doesn't have speed in context menu but buttons works for me in Firefox. But if I put the same code in next cell then buttons doesn't work for next video. If I use different IDs then they work - so problem can be when there are already objects with the same ID.

Comment: I ended up switching to `<button onclick` and it works great. Really happy with this as I couldn't figure it out, thanks again!

Comment: In Jupyter Lab can <shift><right click> (add shift) to get the controls, including video playback speed